# Why jquery code don't work in capybara tests

Tags: jquery, rspec, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a select box to choose number of child, when I choose option other select boxes must appear to choose ages.

I use this code to choose elements

```
search_page.search_room1_child.click
search_page.search_room1_child_options[1].click
search_page.search_room1_child_ages.click
search_page.search_room1_child_ages_options[8].click
```

I use site-prism gem

```
element :search_room1_child, 'select[name="filter[rooms][room1][child]"]'
elements :search_room1_child_options, 'select[name="filter[rooms][room1][child]"] option'
elements :search_room1_child_ages, 'select[name="filter[rooms][room1][child_ages][]"]'
elements :search_room1_child_ages_options, 'select[name="filter[rooms][room1][child_ages][]"] option'
```

I get this error

Failure/Error: search_page.search_room1_child_ages.click

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `click' for []:Capybara::Result
```

Comment: We need more information if there should be a chance to help you. Also try look at the console log and see if there is some error at the page where you code dont work

Comment: In webdriver I see that the first part (choose of child number) work, but select box for ages don't appear.

Comment: we need to see your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by precompiling assets in test environment

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific error you show is because you're trying to call `click` on the result of calling something defined by site_prisms `elements`.  `elements` defines a method that returns multiple elements, so `click` isn't defined on that since `click` only makes sense on a single `element`. You probably meant to have

```
element :search_room1_child_ages, 'select[name="filter[rooms][room1][child_ages][]"]'
```

in your site prism section definition. Although if you're going to be using a lot of elements with names like this you should really be using the built-in Capybara selector types

```
element :search_room1_child_ages, :select, name: "filter[rooms][room1][child_ages][]"
```

or, better yet, look into registering Capybara custom selectors to really clean up your code.

Note: I'm really not sure what your question has to do with jQuery as stated in its title

Comment: The problem with jquery that the ages select box is not add in DOM, when I run test in webdriver I don't see it. I think that's the cause of the error.